# ImageButton(ImageView) in custom layout for actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-custom-view

I'm using actionbarsherlock.

In order to get action modes on bottom([action modes on bottom](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20468014/as1.jpg)) I use

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

But I need to add a button to main action bar, so I use custom view.

```
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);      
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav, new 
         ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Here is custom_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnMore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_day"
    android:onClick="onMoreClick"/>
```

It doesn't metter if I use ImageButton or ImageView with the same properties, so I'll talk about ImageButton.

If I use the ImageButton, I get what I want except of that background is gray.
[image]

If I add a line to previous custom_view.xml, in order to get transperent background(or use ImageView instead)

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

The alpha in icon will be "cropped" and size of button will change.
[image]

**The question is. How to get button with such sizes as on first image(with default gray background) but with transperent background?**

One of the ways to solve a problem is to make a color of the button's background the same as a color of actionbar and it will look like transperent, but I don't think it is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image with transparent background. It can be done in photoshop.

Comment: Erm, what? I use images from [Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack) 

What should I do with them in Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an ImageView instead of an ImageButton? Just set your required image in the imageview and use an onclicklistener to detect clicks like you would do for an ImageButton.

Additionally, you can also just specify the width of your ImageButton and set the padding as required (this is if you want to use android:background="#00000000").

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can add to the button

android:background="yourimagethere"; or maybe android:background=NULL

and it will solve the problem